# Grails - content-type dependent afterInterceptor

Tags: json, grails

Can I set a controller afterInterceptor based on content-type?

Example: only call afterInterceptor if the incoming request type is application/json; otherwise do not call afterInterceptor

I'm not finding a way and the "withFormat" closure approach is going to be cumbersome to set on every action.

I want to convert the model to json only if the incoming request type is json.

Or, are there other ways to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a guard clause to your ***afterInterceptor*** that exits if the request content-type is not JSON.

```
def afterInterceptor = { model ->
    if (request.getHeader('Content-Type')?.startsWith('application/json')) {
        return
    }
    //do your json stuff here
}
```

Or, if you are really interested in the incoming ***Accept*** header, then you would use

```
if (request.format != 'JSON') return
```

Comment: Do we have access to request in the afterInterceptor?  I didn't think so, but will try it out.